# What is the maximum number of columns in MemSQL?

Tags: database, singlestore

There seems to be the same 4096 column limit MySQL has. Is there any way to override this and create larger tables, eg. in columnstore format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The column limit in MemSQL is currently 4096, and it is not tunable. The best way to get around it is to use a JSON column (http://docs.memsql.com/latest/json/json/).

Comment: Thanks! I tried to do this: Simplify the database structure to a very simple design consisting of a single ID column and a JSON column with all the data. However, if I try to use persisted computed columns for the JSON column, MemSQL also complains about too many columns.

Example: `VAR15 AS data::%VAR15 PERSISTED INT(3),` ...

Comment: The 4096 column limit applies to persisted columns as well. You can reference columns directly in JSON in a query with `SELECT data::%VAR15` for example. Generally users reserve computed columns for the most commonly accessed columns.

Comment: @AnkurGoyal is that limit for col store or row store or both?